# AngularJS - Focusable elements inside ng-click on iPad

Tags: angularjs, safari, angular-ui

We have a list of items derived from ng-repeat, each item is clickable with ng-click.

These items may contain form elements and or ui.bootstrap.dropdown elements

On iPad safari and chrome, tapping on the dropdown does not open the menu and the input box does not open the the keyboard, although, sometimes briefly.

Anyone encounter this before?

A narrowed down example would look like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in model.items" ng-click="selectItem(item)">
    <input type="text" />

    <div class="btn-group">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle ">{{item.something}}</span></button>
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
             <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li ng-repeat="sub in item.subs">
                 <a href="#">{{sub.name}}</a>
             </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank-you

Comment: If it's a solely ios issue, it could be related to fastclick.  Have you installed https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick for better ux on ios devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was for all mobile devices and found some bits of information here and there such as the explanation by jbielick here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6432

Used the directive presented by jdhiro on this page https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2017 and seems to work well so far.

example:

```
<input type="text" stop-event="touchend"/>
```